# Strange result of using T1 = unsigned T2 in C++

Tags: c++, types, g++, using, unsigned-integer

The following code confuses me.

https://godbolt.org/z/WcMTYM1q7

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using ll = long long;
using ull = unsigned ll;

int main() {
    ull x = 0;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

This code fails to compile, in g++ 11, but successful to compile in g++ 12 and g++ 13. In g++ 11, compiler says:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'ull' {aka 'long unsigned int'})
```

And I also test the following code.

https://godbolt.org/z/PrePfoa6E

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using ll = long long;
using ull = unsigned ll;
using ull2 = std::make_unsigned_t<ll>;

int main() {
    std::cout << typeid(ll).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(ull).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(ull2).name() << std::endl;
}
```

When using g++ 13 to compile the code, it prints `x`, `j` and `y`, which mean `long long`, `unsigned int` and `unsigned long long`. And when using g++ 11 to compile the code, it prints `x`, `m` and `y`, which mean `long long`, `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`. All in all, `unsigned ll` is not the expected type.

Why does this happen? Is it a compiler bug? When should I use `std::make_unsigned`?

Comment: *"When should I use `std::make_unsigned`?"*  Whenever you need the unsigned version of some type. You might ask yourself, why bother to add `std::make_unsigned_t<x>` to the library if `unsigned x` works just as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using ull = unsigned ll;` is not valid standard C++. You can't add a type-specifier like `unsigned` to a typedef name like `ll`. That's only possible for cv-qualifiers, i.e. `const` and `volatile`, not other qualifiers that change the type like `unsigned`.

The compiler should issue a diagnostic for this code and GCC does correctly do so with `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors`.

That it compiles at all without these flags, but doesn't with them, indicates that it is likely an intended non-standard-conforming behavior to accept this declaration and in that case there is no reason to assume that `unsigned ll` would be `unsigned long long` absent documentation saying so.

[The documentation mentions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Incompatibilities.html) that this syntax was allowed in K&R C for `typedef`s, but not in ISO C. Presumably this is left over for K&R C compatibility where `long long` and `unsigned long long` don't exist and so this syntax seems to not be implemented as expected for these types. And the C++11 `using` declaration is basically just syntactical sugar for `typedef`, so the behavior was probably taken from the `typedef` behavior, even if it doesn't make sense for compatibility. `-pedantic-errors` enforces standards-conformance, so that this compatibility feature is not permitted anymore.

However, the overload resolution failure for GCC 11 looks unintended to me either way and could be explained as a bug fixed in the later versions.

Answer (score 2):

It is a compiler bug.
I don't know why GCC compiles this, but `unsigned ll` definitely is ill-formed code.
The failure in overload resolution is a consequence of allowing this declaration, since declaring `ull` normally as: `unsigned`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long` all work.
Declaring it as `unsinged ll` produces some sort of broken type that isn't truly any of these.

> ```cpp
> using ull = unsigned ll;
> ```

Clang rejects it as it should:

```
<source>:4:22: error: type-id cannot have a name
using ull = unsigned ll;
                     ^~
```

And so does MSVC:

```
<source>(4): error C2187: syntax error: 'll' was unexpected here
```

In general, `unsigned` can only be used in conjunction with (implicit) `int` in a specifier list. You have to use `std::make_unsigned_t<ll>`, otherwise this code is ill-formed.

You can still make GCC reject this by adding the flags:

```py
-Wpedantic -Werror
# or
-pedantic-errors
```